# PyQt5: How can change QInputDialog OkButtonText?

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

**First, I am a Korean Student. So I'm not good at English, Please excuse me.**

I'm Using PyQt5. But I don't know About "How to use `setOkButtonText()`"

How to use `setOkButtonText()` or `setCancelButtonText()`?

and Where I inserting those codes?

Below is part of my code:

```py
import sys

import PyQt5
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5 import uic

class MainDialog(QDialog):
    def __init__(self):
        QDialog.__init__(self, None)
        uic.loadUi(WdmUI, self)
        self.depositButton.clicked.connect(self.depositClicked)
        self.withdrawButton.clicked.connect(self.withdrawClicked)
    def withdrawClicked(self):
        while True:
            money1, ok1 = QInputDialog.getInt\
                (self, "Withdraw", "<font face=\"Malgun Gothic\">Input withdraw amount:</font>", 1000, 0, 10000001)
            QInputDialog.setOkButtonText(self, "OKOK")
```

And this is the error it produces:

> TypeError: setOkButtonText(self, str): first argument of unbound method must have type 'QInputDialog'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it:

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (QWidget, QPushButton, QLineEdit, QHBoxLayout,
                             QInputDialog, QApplication, QDialog)


class Example(QWidget):        
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setWindowTitle('Input dialog')
        
        btn = QPushButton('Dialog')
        btn.clicked.connect(self.showDialog)

        self.le = QLineEdit(self)
        
        layout = QHBoxLayout(self)
        layout.addWidget(btn)
        layout.addWidget(self.le)

    def showDialog(self):
        dialog = QInputDialog(self)
        dialog.setWindowTitle("QInputDialog")
        dialog.setLabelText("Enter Value")
        dialog.setOkButtonText("OKOK")                         # +++
        dialog.setCancelButtonText("NOT OK")                   # +++
        if dialog.exec_() == QDialog.Accepted:
            text = dialog.textValue()
            self.le.setText(text)
        else:
            print("canceled")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = Example()
    ex.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. Can I change QInputDialog's type to getInt? I tried `dialog.getInt()`. But it is create new window and not applicable `setOkButtonText` or `setCancelButtonText`.